# Sonar - Custom C Rule, SSLR C Toolkit - Avoid recursion (+ built in xpath functions)

Tags: xpath, sonarqube

I'm currently working with implementing some MISRA C rules in Sonar. My current rule is to avoid recursion. I started with

```
//statement[@tokenValue=ancestor::functionDefinition/functionDeclarator/functionName/@tokenValue]
```

To avoid using the same function name within a function definition, but of course it is possible to use other functions with the same names, but different signatures.

Therefore I've two questions:

1. Is it possible to find out the method signatures (via built in xpath function, etc.)? Here, i could compare the signature with the call statement.
2. Is it possible to extend the plugin, as there are MISRA rules where it might be more efficient to go through the abstract syntax tree with the sourcecode?
   Thank you really much for your replies:)
   (ps :- are there any documentions about the SSLR C toolkit / built in xpath rules?)

Answer (score 0):

The C plugin is deprecated. It has been replaced by the C/C++ plugin. See http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/.

Before implementing a new coding rule, you should consider whether it is specific to your own context or might benefit others. If it might benefit others, you can propose them on the developer mailing-list. If the SonarQube team find your proposed rules interesting, they may be implemented directly in the related language plugin. It means less maintenance for you, and benefit to others. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules